# specify query conditions when parallelScanning mongodb DBCollection in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I need to get a large DBCollection to the memory. Since `DBCollection.find()` is not working, I  used `DBCollection.parallelScan()` to achieve this. But in parallelScan I can't specify a query condition like in `DBCollection.find(query)`.

Is it possible to use query `BasicDBObject` in `parallelScan`?

Comment: Why/how is `find` not working? Why do you need query conditions if you are bringing the whole collection into memory?

Comment: My query returns around half of the collection. I think find does not work if you are returning more than 30MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` will batch the query results.  By default, the batch size is 20 documents so it's pretty unlikely that `find()` is the culprit.  You're likely holding on to too much data in your application.

Comment: I will recheck on Monday and get back to you.